# How can I check if a single character appears in a string?

Tags: java, validation, string, character

In Java is there a way to check the condition:

"Does this single character appear at all in string x"

**without** using a loop?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are trying to avoid loops?

Comment: You cannot do a general search for the character without a loop. Look up how a Turing Machine works.

Comment: We should assume @barfoon doesn't want the loop to be in their code.  Obviously the machine does a loop somewhere.  Otherwise the question is nonsense.

Comment: I would say java's string manipulation is quite limited

Comment: @barfoon, based on the definition of `single character` and how the user accesses that character, there might be a different usage pattern. I have added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506105/how-can-i-check-if-a-single-character-appears-in-a-string/66324429#66324429)

Answer (score 360, accepted):

You can use [`string.indexOf('a')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29).

If the char `a` is present in `string` :

> it returns the the index of the first occurrence of the character in
>   the character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the
>   character does not occur.

Comment: But there's always a loop behind that call because you can't find a symbol otherwise.

Comment: indexOf() uses a loop internally.

Comment: Thats not what Barfoon asked. B wishes to avoid doing the loop in B's code. Naturally the API needs to do a loop after all a String is an array of characters wrapped up in a nice class with lots of useful methods.

Comment: If there is more than one character 'a', what returend?

Comment: How are these answers getting so many upvotes? The solutions of using `indexOf()` uses loop internally. None of the answers gives correct solution and if someone dares to ask a new question, people declare it `Duplicate`. Really disappointing ;(

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh I don't see how this can be done without a loop. A string is more or less an group of characters. If it is a group (collection, array, etc) then no matter if it is internal or external to the native code, I would expect that you would need a loop in order to find something within the "group". I believe "without using a loop?" is more like "without writing my own loop?".

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh  As long as it works! Who cares :D

Comment: Why would you use `indexOf` when you can use `contains`, which semantically matches what you are actually asking?

Comment: Using a `char` that will be widened to `indexOf(int)` can work correctly only for BMP. For SP, codepoints should be used as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506105/how-can-i-check-if-a-single-character-appears-in-a-string/66324429#66324429)

Answer (score 164):

- [**`String.contains()`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) which checks if the string contains a specified sequence of char values
- [**`String.indexOf()`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) which returns the index within the string of the first occurence of the specified character or substring (there are 4 variations of this method)

Comment: a char isnt a CharSequence so it cant be passed to String.contains(CharSequence).

Comment: To use String.contains() with a single char c do this: **String.contains(Character.toString(c))**

Comment: Or do this if you like short code: `String.contains(""+c)`

Answer (score 38):

I'm not sure what the original poster is asking exactly. Since indexOf(...) and contains(...) both *probably* use loops internally, perhaps he's looking to see if this is possible at all without a loop? I can think of two ways off hand, one would of course be recurrsion:

```
public boolean containsChar(String s, char search) {
    if (s.length() == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return s.charAt(0) == search || containsChar(s.substring(1), search);
}
```

The other is far less elegant, but completeness...:

```
/**
 * Works for strings of up to 5 characters
 */
public boolean containsChar(String s, char search) {
    if (s.length() > 5) throw IllegalArgumentException();

    try {
        if (s.charAt(0) == search) return true;
        if (s.charAt(1) == search) return true;
        if (s.charAt(2) == search) return true;
        if (s.charAt(3) == search) return true;
        if (s.charAt(4) == search) return true;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // this should never happen...
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The number of lines grow as you need to support longer and longer strings of course. But there are no loops/recurrsions at all. You can even remove the length check if you're concerned that that length() uses a loop.

Comment: If you define recursion as a non-loop procedure, you're a geek :D +1 for being creative.

Comment: It's all good for the hard coded length of 5. Otherwise THERE IS A NEED TO DO A LOOP to search for the character. Not to be pedantic but, the proof of this is shown by the definition of a Turing Machine. The foundation of a computational device.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I feel at the end of the day, a recursion is a loop in disguise isn't it? And it may leads to more memory consumption than an ordinary loop in some scenarios.

Answer (score 14):

You can use 2 methods from the `String` class.

- [**`String.contains()`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) which checks if the string contains a specified sequence of char values
- [**`String.indexOf()`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) which returns the index within the string of the first occurence of the specified character or substring or returns -1 if the character is not found (there are 4 variations of this method)

Method 1:

```
String myString = "foobar";
if (myString.contains("x") {
    // Do something.
}
```

Method 2:

```
String myString = "foobar";
if (myString.indexOf("x") >= 0 {
    // Do something.
}
```

Links by: [Zach Scrivena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20029/zach-scrivena)

Answer (score 12):

```
String temp = "abcdefghi";
if(temp.indexOf("b")!=-1)
{
   System.out.println("there is 'b' in temp string");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("there is no 'b' in temp string");
}
```

Comment: isn't this the exact duplicate of the accepted answer ?, we acknowledge your effort but you should try finding some unanswered question and answer them.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to check the same string often you can calculate the character occurrences up-front. This is an implementation that uses a bit array contained into a long array:

```
public class FastCharacterInStringChecker implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final long[] l = new long[1024]; // 65536 / 64 = 1024

public FastCharacterInStringChecker(final String string) {
    for (final char c: string.toCharArray()) {
        final int index = c >> 6;
        final int value = c - (index << 6);
        l[index] |= 1L << value;
    }
}

public boolean contains(final char c) {
    final int index = c >> 6; // c / 64
    final int value = c - (index << 6); // c - (index * 64)
    return (l[index] & (1L << value)) != 0;
}}
```

Comment: I tried your solution on a similar problem I have. My closest solution was over 1500 miliseconds for string1 length 63k and string2 length 95k. Your solution spits out a result in 3-5 milliseconds. Can you please edit your solution to include an explanation? Please?

Answer (score 4):

To check if something does not exist in a string, you at least need to look at each character in a string.  So even if you don't explicitly use a loop, it'll have the same efficiency.  That being said, you can try using str.contains(""+char).

Comment: Agreed. At some point, somebody, somewhere needs to construct a loop to do this. Fortunately the Java API does this or our code would be very cluttered!

Answer (score 3):

Is the below what you were looking for?

```
int index = string.indexOf(character);
return index != -1;
```

Comment: Why do you have  `&& string.lastIndexOf(character) != index`

Answer (score 3):

`String.contains(String)` or `String.indexOf(String)` - suggested

```java
"abc".contains("Z"); // false - correct
"zzzz".contains("Z"); // false - correct
"Z".contains("Z"); // true - correct
"and".contains(""); // true - correct
"and".contains(""); // false - correct
"and".indexOf(""); // 0 - correct
"and".indexOf(""); // -1 - correct
```

`String.indexOf(int)` and carefully considered `String.indexOf(char)` with char to `int` widening

```java
"and".indexOf("".charAt(0)); // 0 though incorrect usage has correct output due to portion of correct data
"and".indexOf("".charAt(0)); // 0 -- incorrect usage and ambiguous result
"and".indexOf("".codePointAt(0)); // -1 -- correct usage and correct output
```

### The discussions around character is ambiguous in Java world

#### can the value of `char` or `Character` considered as single character?

**No**. In the context of unicode characters, `char` or `Character` can sometimes be `part of a single character` and should not be treated as `a complete single character` logically.

#### if not, what should be considered as single character (logically)?

Any system supporting character encodings for Unicode characters should consider unicode's codepoint as single character.

So Java should do that very clear & loud rather than exposing too much of internal implementation details to users.

`String` class is bad at abstraction (though it requires confusingly good amount of `understanding of its encapsulations to understand the abstraction`  and hence an `anti-pattern`).

#### How is it different from general `char` usage?

`char` can be only be mapped to a character in Basic Multilingual Plane.

Only `codePoint - int` can cover the complete range of Unicode characters.

#### Why is this difference?

`char` is internally treated as `16-bit` unsigned value and could not represent all the unicode characters using UTF-16 internal representation using only `2-bytes`. Sometimes, values in a `16-bit` range have to be combined with another `16-bit` value to correctly define character.

Without getting too verbose, the usage of `indexOf`, `charAt`, `length` and such methods should be more explicit. Sincerely hoping Java will add new `UnicodeString` and `UnicodeCharacter` classes with clearly defined  abstractions.

#### Reason to prefer `contains` and not `indexOf(int)`

1. Practically there are many code flows that treat a logical character as `char` in java.
2. In Unicode context, `char` is not sufficient
3. Though the `indexOf` takes in an `int`, `char` to `int` conversion masks this from the user and user might do something like `str.indexOf(someotherstr.charAt(0))`(unless the user is aware of the exact context)
4. So, treating everything as `CharSequence` (aka `String`) is better

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("and".indexOf("".charAt(0))); // 0 though incorrect usage has correct output due to portion of correct data
        System.out.println("and".indexOf("".charAt(0))); // 0 -- incorrect usage and ambiguous result
        System.out.println("and".indexOf("".codePointAt(0))); // -1 -- correct usage and correct output
        System.out.println("and".contains("")); // true - correct
        System.out.println("and".contains("")); // false - correct
    }
```

### Semantics

1. `char` can handle most of the practical use cases. Still its better to use codepoints within programming environment for future extensibility.
2. `codepoint` should handle nearly all of the technical use cases around encodings.
3. Still, [Grapheme Clusters](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries) falls out of the scope of `codepoint` level of abstraction.
4. Storage layers can choose `char` interface if `int`s are too costly(doubled). Unless storage cost is the only metric, its still better to use `codepoint`. Also, its better to treat storage as `byte` and delegate semantics to business logic built around storage.
5. Semantics can be abstracted at multiple levels. `codepoint` should become lowest level of interface and other semantics can be built around `codepoint` in runtime environment.

Comment: that is a very happy answer :)

Comment: Best answer I've read in quite a while, well done

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using the indexOf() method on the string class. [See the API documentation for this method](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))

Answer (score 1):

```
package com;
public class _index {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="be proud to be an indian";
        char ch=s1.charAt(s1.indexOf('e'));
        int count = 0; 
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++) {
            if(s1.charAt(i)=='e'){
                System.out.println("number of E:=="+ch);
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total count of E:=="+count);
    }
}
```

Comment: and `for` is not a loop now?

Answer (score 0):

```
static String removeOccurences(String a, String b)
{
    StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder(a);

    for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++){
        char ch = b.charAt(i);  
        System.out.println(ch+"  first index"+a.indexOf(ch));

        int lastind = a.lastIndexOf(ch);

    for(int k=new String(s2).indexOf(ch);k > 0;k=new String(s2).indexOf(ch)){
            if(s2.charAt(k) == ch){
                s2.deleteCharAt(k);
        System.out.println("val of s2 :             "+s2.toString());
            }
        }
      }

    System.out.println(s1.toString());

    return (s1.toString());
}
```

Comment: Here we are looking for occurrences of every character from String b present in String a and deleting the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It will check the char is present or not. If it is present then the return value is >= 0 otherwise it's -1. Here I am printing alphabets that is not present in the input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void letters()
    {
         System.out.println("Enter input char");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         String input = sc.next();
         System.out.println("Output : ");
        for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
            if (input.toUpperCase().indexOf(alphabet) < 0) 
                System.out.print(alphabet + " ");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        letters();
    }
}
```

**Ouput Example**

```
Enter input char
nandu
Output : 
B C E F G H I J K L M O P Q R S T V W X Y Z
```

Comment: please do not put the explanation in code block

Answer (score 0):

If you see the source code of **indexOf** in JAVA:

```
public int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex) {

        final int max = value.length;

        if (fromIndex < 0) {

            fromIndex = 0;

        } else if (fromIndex >= max) {

            // Note: fromIndex might be near -1>>>1.

            return -1;

        }


        if (ch < Character.MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT) {

            // handle most cases here (ch is a BMP code point or a

            // negative value (invalid code point))

            final char[] value = this.value;

            for (int i = fromIndex; i < max; i++) {

                if (value[i] == ch) {

                    return i;

                }

            }

            return -1;

        } else {

            return indexOfSupplementary(ch, fromIndex);

        }

    }
```

you can see it uses a for loop for finding a character. Note that each *indexOf* you may use in your code, is equal to one loop.

**So, it is unavoidable to use loop for a single character.**

However, if you want to find a special string with more different forms, use useful libraries such as `util.regex`, it deploys stronger algorithm to match a character or a  string pattern with *Regular Expressions*. For example to find an email in a string:

```
String regex = "^(.+)@(.+)$";
 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
```

If you don't like to use regex, just use a loop and `charAt` and try to cover all cases in one loop.

Be careful recursive methods has more overhead than loop, so it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

how about one uses this ;

```
let text = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
let result = text.includes("world");
console.log(result) ....// true
```

the result will be a `true` or `false`

this always works for me

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to check if char appears at all in some string without atleast going over the string once using loop / recursion ( the built-in methods like indexOf also use a loop )

If the no. of times you look up if a char is in string *x* is more way more than the length of the string than I would recommend using a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) data structure as that would be more efficient than simply using `indexOf`

```
String s = "abc";

// Build a set so we can check if character exists in constant time O(1)
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
int len = s.length();
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) set.add(s.charAt(i));

// Now we can check without the need of a loop
// contains method of set doesn't use a loop unlike string's contains method
set.contains('a') // true
set.contains('z') // false
```

Using set you will be able to check if character exists in a string in **constant time** O(1) but you will also use additional memory ( Space complexity will be O(n) ).