# Java: check if string contains more than one character

Tags: java, javafx, contains, ends-with

I would like to check my inputted string on a comma, which is pretty easy ( just used this: [How can I check if a single character appears in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506105/how-can-i-check-if-a-single-character-appears-in-a-string)). Now I want to check if a character is present more than once. (in this case a comma (/u002C)) I have created this code:

```
public static void addTextLimiterDouble(final TextField tf, final int maxLength, final Button submitButton) {
    tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {

            if (oldValue.contains("\u002C") && newValue.endsWith("\u002C")) {
                tf.setText(oldValue);
            }
    }
});
```

This gives a StackOverflow error, because it seems it can not get out of the loop. Can anyone explain why it can't?

Note: I know there are maybe more ways to check for more than one character, but I am just curious why this gives me an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the situation (actually, that's most likely the situation where you are in) where you are editing a string that *ends* in a comma. When you change something else in that string, then your `if` statement (`if (oldValue.contains("\u002C") && newValue.endsWith("\u002C"))`) returns `true` and you try to revert to the old value by calling `tf.setText()`

However- that changes the text! And your `ChangeListener` is invoked again. The new value ends in a comma (you were reverting back to a value that ends in a comma) and the old value also contains a comma, so again, your listener calls `tf.setText()`.

After that, it invokes your `ChangeListener` because the text was changed. And again... *ad nauseum*

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! I thought the ChangeListener would only be invoked by the user alternating the text in the textfield, but this is obviously not true.

Answer (score 1):

`String.endsWith` checks if the passed `String` is present at the end of the `String` calling the method, but that is not what you are willing to do.

This is what I would do :

```
int index = myString.indexOf(ch);
boolean moreThanOnce = index != -1 && index != myString.lastIndexOf(ch);
```

However your test seems weird to me since it tests something on both `oldValue` and `newValue`. If I understood well what you want to do you should only consider one of those two.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, and for your alternative for this. It works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

You add a Listener to your TextField. Then you override the `changed()` method. In this method you call `setText()` !! This will invoke the Listeners' `changed()` again .... so you end up in an infinite loop ...