# Error when the user enters values not in String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
String[] alpha = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
```

I have made the Array above including all the letters in the alphabet for a letter guessing game.

I am not sure how I could get an error message to appear if the user enters something outside of these values of the alphabet eg. a number? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: regex? like `if(value.equals("\\d"))` --> error. or even easier, vonvert the array to a list and perform a check like this: `if(!list.contains(value))` -->error

Comment: `!input.matches("[a-z]")` should work... Forget the array of the alphabet

Answer (score 4):

You can convert it into a `List` and use `contains`, e.g.:

```
String[] alpha = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(alpha);
System.out.println(list.contains("a"))
```

If you want case insensitive comparison then you can use `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: This has worked in giving me the error, although it is outputting 26 errors when i try input a number, would you know how this could be fixed? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: Is the line of code System.out.println(list.contains("a")) needed? I have tried an if statement instead which could be causing the repeated error messages.  if(!list.contains(guess)){
              System.out.println("Out of range");

Comment: `if(!list.contains(guess))` should work as long as `guess` is a String.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a character array than that one . Example is given here https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-tochararray. Then you could use indexof method to see if the user entered value is valid as explained here [How can I check if a single character appears in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506105/how-can-i-check-if-a-single-character-appears-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:-

```
if (! ArrayUtils.contains( alpha, "[i-dont-exist]" ) ) {
    try{
        throw new Exception("Not Found !");
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

[Documentation Here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

if the purpose to check the existence of the elements inside collections its more reasonable to use a set since the access time is constanct

so Instead

```
   Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();//if not java 8 make it HashSet<String>
   set.put("a") // do this for all the strings you would like to check
```

Then to check if a string exists in this set

```
if(set.contains(str)) //str is the string you want to make sure it exists in the collections
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach if you would like to stick with array instead of other data structures.

1. Create a method that return true if the user input is present in the array, otherwise return false

   ```
   public static boolean isValid(String input) {
       String[] alpha = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
           "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", 
           "w", "x", "y", "z"};

       for(String s: alpha) {
           if(input.equals(s)) {  //use input.equalsIgnoreCase(s) for case insensitive comparison
               return true;    //user input is valid
           }
       }

       return false;   //user input is not valid
   }
   ```
2. In the calling method, simply pass the user input to `isValid`

   ```
   //write some codes here to receive user input.....

   if(!isValid(input))
       System.out.println("Oops, you have entered invalid input!");
   ```