# How to find if a string contains any objects in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, chars

Say if I have the following code

```
String sum = "(5+5)/2*6";
char[] bodmasChars = {'+','-','*','/','.'.'(',')'};
```

Is there a way to check whether the string contains any of the elements in my char[]?

Comment: Did you take a look at the methods that the ``String`` class offers you?

Comment: Yes, there is, and any google search for "[java string contains char](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+string+contains+char)" will show you how. Once you have an actual problem, please ask, but do your research first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a single character appears in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506105/how-can-i-check-if-a-single-character-appears-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

A regex

```
String sum = "(5+5)/2*6";
if (sum.matches("(?s).*[-\\+\\*/\\.()].*")) { ...
```

`(?s)` lets `.` also match newlines.
`[...]` is group of possible character or character ranges. Probably have a backslash too many.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with Regex or with Simple as :

```
String s="(5+5)/2*6";
        if((s.contains("+")||(s.contains("-")||(s.contains("-"))||....))
                {
            System.out.println("yes");
                }
```