# how do i iterate through a string of characters to find a specific character?

Tags: java

I am having a hard time figuring out why my code will not work. I am trying to stop the output on a specific letter, but it keeps iterating through the entire string instead. This is what I have,

```
public static char stringIterator(String string) {      
    System.out.println(string);//Keep this line
    char lastChar = string.charAt(string.length() - 1);
    if (lastChar == 'M') {
        return lastChar;
    }
    else if (string.length() == 1) {
        return lastChar;
    }
    else {
        return stringIterator(string.substring(0, string.length() - 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: `return stringIterator(string.substring(0, string.length() - 2));` should be `return stringIterator(string.substring(0, string.length() - 1));` no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a single character appears in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506105/how-can-i-check-if-a-single-character-appears-in-a-string)

Comment: @Zephyr You are correct, but this is _actually_ an iterative function that calls upon itself.  Similar concept though.

Comment: What is your end goal here? To print out a new line, subtracting a single letter each time, until you reach an "M?"

Comment: @Zephyr thats exactly what im trying to do. i am trying to subtract the last character of the string and print out a new string until i find the character i am looking for. i hope that makes sense

Comment: @Zephyr also i am trying to find this character recursively

Comment: Then really all you need to do is change the last `return` statement as @GBlodgett said.

Comment: @Zephyr it should be changed to return stringIterator(string.substring(0, string.length() - 1))  ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I got it to work now :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to just see if it has it then you would use

```
string.contains('char');
```

if you want to traverse/iterate then

```
for( int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
    if(string.at(i) == '#')
    { //whatever you want here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be over-thinking this... 
Java has very good resources for dealing with Strings, check out the docs:
[Java String Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
if (string.contains('m')){
    //dostuff
    }

    if (string.endsWith('m')){
    //dostuff
    }
```

etc.

As for your iteration problem, you'll have to post the rest of your code, as it looks like your Loop is Calling `stringIterator(String)` from somewhere outside this method.
(It's not really a stringIterator if it doesn't iterate anything)

Also this last line of code:

```
return stringIterator(string.substring(0, string.length() - 2));
```

Is recursive (calls itself)... which can cause you trouble. There's certainly uses for recursion, finding something in a 1d array is not one of those uses. Assuming your loop is working properly this could be what's preventing you from stopping the output.

Answer (score 0):

public String substring(int begIndex, int endIndex) - returns a new string that is a substring of the string 
Parameters :
beginIndex :  the begin index, inclusive.
endIndex :  the end index, exclusive.
(eg):  String string = "NAME"
       string.substring(0, string.length() - 2) - returns "NA"
       string.substring(0, string.length() - 1) - returns "NAM" . Use this, thus you will be able to subtract the last character of the string.

Iterative approach

```
     public static char stringIterator(String string) {
     char lastChar = string.charAt(0);
       for(int i = string.length()-1 ;i>=0;i--) {
           System.out.println(string);//Keep this line
           lastChar = string.charAt(i);
           if (string.length() == 1 || lastChar == 'M') {
              break;
           } else {
              string = string.substring(0, i);
           }
        }
        return lastChar;
      }
```